# What happens to a Triage Review-Tie?

Tags: support, triage

I just reviewed a question in Triage which, coincidentally, I had already just offered a suggested edit.  The question was already pretty clear but I thought it could use a few formatting changes.  Knowing I had proposed this edit, I chose **Looks OK** - (*Was this the correct thing to do?*).

In doing so, I saw the following resulting tie in votes for **Looks OK** and **Should Be Improved**:

[image: 3-3 Triage Tie]

What happens in a case like this?  I assume **Should Be Improved** wins out because it "crossed the finish line first", but I'm more interested in concrete evidence.

Comment: ...but the image states that the consensus was "Looks OK"...so I'm not sure why you'd think that one or the other won out.  A developer would need to see which one has more weight or if it really is first person wins.

Comment: @Makoto True, the consensus does state that, though I'm willing to bet when Bruno Belotti clicked **Should Be Improved**, his screen read "*The consensus is this post **Should Be Improved**.*"

Comment: I strongly doubt that.  If a consensus has been reached on a triage item I don't believe it's eligible for review anymore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The result of that review task was that the question Should Be Improved. The review task was *already* completed almost a minute before it recorded your review action. It allowed your action to be recorded because you were already looking at it before it completed.

The message at the top stating the consensus doesn't look back at what actually happened. It just sees that the review is now completed, and throws in whatever action you clicked as the "consensus" because it assumes that was actually the final action. That consensus line does not show up for users if you load the page later.

The system did behave as expected here - it created a new review task for the question in the Help & Improvement queue as a result of the Should Be Improved result, which was later invalidated because the question was edited (via your suggested edit being approved).

Comment: That's not what I've seen in the past: I've instead seen "This review completed X minutes ago" or the like, where it's clear that my review vote did not count. Did this get changed recently?

Comment: @Nathan Only some of them allow review actions post-completion, but this behavior has existed since the new review queues were created a long time ago.

Comment: Fair enough. I've seen this in Triage itself, though, was my point.